# Mobile website is not showing images according to the width of viewport

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I am designing a mobile website and when I see my website in portrait view on iphone/ipod its layout, images everything is perfect but when I change to landscape view everything is showing a little bit zoomed-in. I have tried all the meta tag (viewport) attributes:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

What am I missing? I want to continue to allow users to zoom, I just don't want the orientation change to zoom my content in.

Answer (score 0):

The guys behind jQuery Mobile have [a solution to this](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/a_fix_for_the_ios_orientationchange_zoom_bug/). It works by checking the accelerometer data and disabling zoom while the device is changing orientation.